# Compiling fortran program with archive library results in undefined reference state

Tags: fortran, static-libraries, gfortran, archive

I've made a small library which I archived. I am trying to use that archive when compiling my programs, but I end up with an undefined reference state.

Here is an example.

`main.f90`:

```
program main
    use mymod, only : f
    implicit none
    real :: a, b

    a = 5
    call f(a, b)
    print *, b
end program main
```

`mymod.f90`

```
module mymod
    implicit none
    private
    public :: f

contains
    subroutine f(a, b)
        real, intent(in) :: a
        real, intent(out) :: b

        b = sqrt(a)

    end subroutine f
end module mymod
```

Creation of the archive:

```
$ gfortran -c mymod.f90 
$ ar crv libmymod.a mymod.o
a - mymod.o
```

Attempted compilation of `main.f90`:

```
$ gfortran -c main.f90
$ gfortran -L. -lmymod main.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `MAIN__':
main.f90:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `__mymod_MOD_f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is this an issue with the archive, the compilation (and/or linking) of `main.f90`, and/or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The linker does a single pass and works on the arguments from left to right.  If the line reads

```
gfortran -L. -lmymod main.o
```

The linker looks at mymod first, sees there is nothing to resolve and then moves on to main.o.  When it gets to main.o, it needs mymod so it looks for the next parameter and not finding any, returns an error.  If the link line is changed to

```
gfortran main.o -L. -lmymod
```

that will resolve the issue.  With libraries, the linker only takes what it needs.  Depending on how the archive has been built, it is not unheard of to have the same library several times.  Something like

```
gfortran main.o -L. -lmymod -lmymod -lmymod
```

Comment: I can test when I am at my computer tomorrow, but I thought that the dependency order should increase from left to right. This means that the leftmost file should not have any dependency and the next one can depend on the previous one, and the next one on the previous two, etc. that way the linker would have encountered the necessary file before reaching the point where they are needed. That's why I placed `main.o` last since it depends on `mymod`, which would have already been seen by the linker (through the static library).

Comment: *nix linkers are single pass and use a _only take what you need_ algorithm.  Windows linkers  are different.

Comment: I'm on a Linux machine.